# Does Ubuntu 15.10 server iso include Openstack?

Tags: 15.10, openstack, openstack-autopilot

While reading the release notes for 15.10 I read(https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WilyWerewolf/ReleaseNotes)

Ubuntu Server
OpenStack Liberty

Ubuntu 15.10 includes the latest OpenStack release, Liberty, including the following components:

- OpenStack Identity - Keystone
  .

  .

  .

Does this mean Openstack Liberty is included as part of the iso? Or Does it mean 15.10 supports Liberty?

PS: My apologies if this is a trivial question. I am new to Linux and Openstack

Comment: "Ubuntu 15.10 includes the latest OpenStack release, Liberty" Yes, the release version of Openstack and all the components in the list that follows it on the ISO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenStack Liberty is included in Ubuntu 15.10 in the sense that it is included in the Ubuntu 15.10 package archive, which resides on the Internet. You will still need to install and configure the software.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/nova-common